# Is there a SaaS solution for converting Excel spreadsheets to PDFs?

Tags: excel, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a SaaS solution out there (preferably with a RESTful API) to convert Excel spreadsheets (Office 2010 format) to PDFs?

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.Cells for Cloud can convert Excel spreadsheets to PDF. The web pages and documentation are a bit messy, but we are working over these to give a better user experience.

To quickly get started on PDF conversion, you can try any of the below examples:

1. [Convert Workbook (on cloud) to PDF](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellscloud/Convert+Workbook+to+different+File+Formats+%28.NET+REST%29)
2. [Convert local workbook to PDF](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellscloud/Convert+Local+Workbook+to+different+File+Formats+%28.NET+REST%29), it first uploads and then converts.

I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks for the response Saqib, but per my response below I'm pretty displeased with your documentation and the usability of your website.

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose Cloud](https://cloud.aspose.com/App) exists, but their documentation is horrendous and their website is maze-like.

Comment: look at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6200a18f-0213-437d-b1ee-e866b1c46524

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  A few points: 1) Please enter answers as answers instead of comments.  2) I asked for a SaaS solution, which this is not.